# Exception in subscribe loop: Subscribe key not configured

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, pubnub

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting this exception please? Even though I have the suscribe key configured, it seems like it is not.

Here is the exception: "Exception in subscribe loop: Subscribe key not configured
reconnection policy is disabled, please handle reconnection manually."

```py
import time

from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from backend.blockchain.block import Block

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.suscribe_key = 'sub-c-6d0fe192-dee4-11ea-9b19-...'
pnconfig.publish_key = 'pub-c-c3553c68-bf24-463c-ae43-...'

CHANNELS = {
'TEST': 'TEST',
'BLOCK': 'BLOCK'
}

class Listener(SubscribeCallback):
    def __init__(self, blockchain):
        self.blockchain = blockchain

        def message(self, pubnub, message_object):
            print('\n-- Channel: {message_object.channel} | Message: {message_object.message}')

            if message_object.channel == CHANNELS['BLOCK']:
                block = Block.from_json(message_object.message)
                potential_chain = self.blockchain.chain[:]
                potential_chain.append(block)

                try:
                    self.blockchain.replace_chain(potential_chain)
                    print('\n -- Successfully replaced the local chain')
                except Exception as e:
                    print('\n -- Did not replace chain: {e}')

class PubSub():
    """
    Handles the publish/subscribe layer of the application.
    Provides communication between the nodes of the blockchain network.
    """
    def __init__(self, blockchain):
        self.pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)
        self.pubnub.subscribe().channels(CHANNELS.values()).execute()
        self.pubnub.add_listener(Listener(blockchain))

        def publish(self, channel, message):
            """
            Publish the message object to the channel.
            """
            self.pubnub.publish().channel(channel).message(message).sync()

        def broadcast_block(self, block):
            """
            Broadcast a block object to all nodes.
            """
            self.publish(CHANNELS['BLOCK'], block.to_json())

            def main():
                pubsub = PubSub()

                time.sleep(1)

                pubsub.publish(CHANNELS['TEST'], { 'foo': 'bar' })

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    main()
```

Comment: I had some issues running your code as is but reformatted/indented and updated above in your question so that copy/pasting your code will work without error.

Comment: But I couldn't figure out what to install for `backend.blockchain.block` so I couldn't test run. But you mention the reconnection issue. Is your script running successfully then after some time (after a disconnect?) are you getting this error?

Comment: No Craig it was not running at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the error "Exception in subscribe loop: Subscribe key not configured reconnection policy is disabled, please handle reconnection manually.".

I used the code block:

```
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = "my_subkey"
pnconfig.publish_key = "my_pubkey"
pnconfig.ssl = True
pnconfig.uuid = "my_custom_uuid"
pnconfig.reconnect_policy = "LINEAR"
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)
```

from page: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/api-reference-configuration
and added:

```
PNReconnectionPolicy.NONE
```

from page: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/api-reference-configuration